# Does tlmgr show the actual package versions?

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

Today I installed TeXLive 2013 next to 2012 and updated all the PATHs to point to 2013. My main motivation for updating is the new version of LuaTeX.

When calling `luatex -v` in a terminal, I also see that I now indeed have the latest version (`beta-0.76.0-2013061708  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)`). However, when I open `tlmgr` it says I rather have `0.70.1`. See the screenshot below:

[image: TLMGR and terminal show different versions.]

My question is now: does `tlmgr` actually show the correct package versions? Is anything going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you have to set up it to point to the newest distribution of your TeXlive.

Comment: I noticed that some packages in the list are newer versions than those of TexLive 2012, which I did by calling `tlmgr` 2012 from its path `/usr/loca/texlive/2012/bin/tlmgr` and comparing it to `tlmgr` 2013. That is why I am assuming both do indeed point to their correct, respective repositories. Thus the confusion: if they point at the correct location, why does `tlmgr` show this weird package version?

Comment: I have the same here. If you double click on the version number in tlmgr gui a window will pop up which says "local catalogue version = 0.70" (Wrong version number) and then "Warning, catalogue versions might be lagging behind or be simply wrong."

Comment: The same on MacTeX (2013); probably it's simply a wrong catalogue entry.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's enough of an answer I suppose, so feel free to write one! Is there any place I can report this wrong version number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several comments already stated the fact, here some additional explanations:

- tlmgr works purely with the revision numbers
- the version numbers are taken from the catalogue and are purely informative
- the catalogue might be outdated
- in this case probably the last version of luatex that has been uploaded to CTAN is the specified version, but in TeX Live there are newer sources

Hope that helps

Norbert